# Easiest way to get to Paraguay from Puerto Iguazu?

Tags: budget, transportation, argentina, paraguay, iguazu-falls

I'm in Puerto Iguazu for a couple of days to see the waterfalls there. It seems to be pretty simple to get to Brazil. But I would also like to go to Paraguay. However, on Google Maps, I can't see any bridge over to Paraguay.

So what is the easiest and cheapest way to get to Paraguay? It is also ok, if it is just for a couple of minutes.

Comment: Via Brazil? According to [Wikivoyage](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Puerto_Iguazu) there's even a bus that lets you cross between Paraguay and Argentina without passing Brazil immigration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's entirely possible, cheap, and simple.  Go to the main bus terminal in Puerto Iguazu.  Get on a bus going to Ciudad del Este (it'll likely just say 'Paraguay'), and it travels across into Brazil to Foz Iguacu, and then across another bridge into Ciudad del Este.

You'll go through customs/border at Argentina/Brazil, and then...probably again going into Paraguay.  Talk to the bus driver, at this point it gets a little sketchy, but...yeah, sometimes they just skip the border.

From [my blog post on doing exactly this trip](http://www.marksmayo.com/2010/07/24/hypothetically-how-to-break-into-paraguay-and-getting-a-blood-test-in-spanish/):

> Let’s just say hypothetically there’s this bus, and there’s this
>   hypothetical driver, who upon hearing that the only non-local on the
>   bus only wants to go into the border town, can’t be bothered getting
>   the tourist a stamp, drives on through the express customs lane for
>   locals, and says he can just do the same on the way back after picking
>   the tourist up again. Imagine that. Hypothetically of course.
>   Hypothetically said tourist would hypothetically be in Paraguay
>   without a visa and without a stamp, wandering around Ciudad del Este.

But yes, there is a bus, and it does take you via Ciudad del Este - and indeed it continues all the way to Asuncion if you really wanted to go that far.  It's very easy, and all it really requires is you getting on the bus.  But do make sure that you have a visa for Paraguay, and check whether you need one for Brazil as well.

Comment: That sounds not bad, but is there a way to avoid Brazil immigration?

Comment: @RoflcoptrException well the bus didn't really seem to deal with Brazil as I guess you were in 'transit' the whole way through Brazil (as long as you didn't get off the bus).  So there was no dealing with them (on my hypothetical bus, at least) ;)